# Why is there a time limit on editing your own comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sorry if this is a dumb question or duplicate.  If it is a dupe, it's been down voted beyond search-ability.

I've posted a comment or two here and there, and got up from my computer and realized I misstated something, or left something out, etc. etc.  And, my comment was closed to editing.  In those cases I merely deleted them, and rewrote, but I'm wondering why there is a time limit in general?

And, in particular, why so short?

Comment: [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78573/why-is-the-time-limit-for-editing-comments-only-5-minutes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike posts, comments are light-weight and don't have an edit history. This is why editing privileges for comments are restricted.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense to me.  I just would like more than 5 minutes to edit, maybe 30 min . . .

Comment: @DavidM That might be a problem for quick back and forth exchanges in comments.